# PyQGIS QGSExpression translate nothing happen

Tags: python, pyqgis, expression, qgsexpression, translate

I'm trying to use this expreission and apparently works if I print the result, but nothing happen in the map canvas.

Do you have some suggestions?

```
from qgis.core import  *

from qgis.utils import iface

a = iface.activeLayer()

a.startEditing()

e1 = QgsExpression('translate($geometry,10.0,10.0)')
                
context = QgsExpressionContext()

context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(a))

for f in a.getFeatures():        
    context.setFeature(f)
    d=e1.evaluate(context) 
    print(d)
    a.updateFeature(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two lines which are `f.setGeometry(d)` and `a.commitChanges()`

```python
from qgis.core import  *

from qgis.utils import iface

a = iface.activeLayer()

a.startEditing()

e1 = QgsExpression('translate($geometry,10.0,10.0)')
                
context = QgsExpressionContext()

context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(a))

for f in a.getFeatures():        
    context.setFeature(f)
    d=e1.evaluate(context) 
    print(d)
    f.setGeometry(d)
    a.updateFeature(f)

a.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the geometry of the feature is not set based on the expression calculation. I've updated your code adding the setGeometry() method after the translation and commitChanges() for ending the editing session after the geometry modification and it worked when I tried to replicate the case.

```
from qgis.core import  *

from qgis.utils import iface

a = iface.activeLayer()

a.startEditing()

e1 = QgsExpression('translate($geometry,10.0,10.0)')
                
context = QgsExpressionContext()

context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(a))

for f in a.getFeatures():        
    context.setFeature(f)
    d=e1.evaluate(context) 
    f.setGeometry(d) #Update feature geometry
    a.updateFeature(f)

a.commitChanges() #Ending editing session on layer
```